# String to str slice, str slice does not live long enough

Tags: string, static, rust, slice, borrow-checker

OK, here's my MCVE, right off the bat.

```
fn do_something (string: &'static str) -> Result<&str, isize> {
    Ok(string)
}

fn main() {
    let place = Some("hello".to_string());
    match place {
        Some(input) => {
            let place = &input[..];
            let something = do_something(place);
        }
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out a way in which to satisfy `do_something`. In my actual code, `do_something` is a library function, so I can't change it's signature.

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the function's signature, then you either need to use a string literal to create a `&'static str` or leak memory.

i.e. either do this:

```
do_something("hello");
```

or this (bad idea, will probably break, only works on nightly):

```
let place = Some("hello".to_string());
if let Some(s) = place {
    do_something(unsafe { std::mem::transmute(s.into_boxed_str()) });
}
```